# Can a Sitecore LaunchPad button open a XML dialog or trigger command which opens up SheerUI dialog

Tags: sheer-ui, commands, launchpad

I want to open a dialog (sheer-ui) on click of launchpad button. Tried following [Link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/can-a-sitecore-launchpad-button-be-attached-to-a-sitecore-powershell-script) with no luck.
is there a way to wire up click of launchpad button to call a command ?
I can do similar via a content editor ribbon button & have to replicate on launchpad button click.